# Reload data on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

how to reload in UITableView class.

I am  using the reloadData method but it's not working.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
     if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) 
    {
        [self init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)init
{   

    appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appdelegate readLiteratureFromDatabase];
    tbl_obj.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    tbl_obj.delegate = self;
    tbl_obj.dataSource = self;  
    [tbl_obj reloadData];
    array_content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return self;
}
```

Here the init method call in another class. So at that time table are not reload.

please help!

Comment: reloadData is for UITableView class, what do you want to reload in your UIView class ? put context code in order to get help you need

Comment: You need to provide more information - what are you actually doing? Please post some code snippets. Otherwise noone will be able to properly answer your "question"...

Comment: reloadData only works on UITableView. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

May be that you might not have attached `DataSource` and `Delegate` to your XIB

or

You can do it through code using:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

Also you have to add it as below:

```
@interface <YourViewControllerName>:UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

**EDIT:**

But you should try and understand that your controls like UITableView cannot be directly called and set into your UIView class.

It should be UIViewController only then it is possible to add and fillup the data into the TableView.

So your option is to call the data delegate and datasource methods and also the reloadData on the ViewController which works as parentView for the this UIView.

So unless you do this way, I fear that it is not possible.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Also **One more important point** is that you have to initialize the array first before calling `[tableView reloadData]` method

Comment: Do you initialize and give values to your array before calling reloadData?

Comment: Try initializing array and Reloading your tableView on `viewWillAppear` method. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I am used UIView class. So I can't use the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: @Sam : But try and understand that your controls like TableView cannot be directly called and set into your UIView class. It should be UIViewController only then it is possible to add and fillup the data into the TableView. so your option is to call the data delegate and datasource methods and also the `reloadData` on the ViewController which works as parentView for the this UIView. So unless you do this way, I fear that it is not possible. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please read the **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: thanks,for your suggestion I take the viewcontroller & add that as a subview and it,s working. reload the table data

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code it appears that you really need to read this;

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

You should not have a method called `init` that does not call up to super, that will eventually hose things.

Setting your `docs` ivar to an empty immutable string does nothing but waste memory. Eventually you will need to set docs to something real, wait till that point to do any allocation.

Next download the TableViewSuite sample from here;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

And take a look at the simple sample.

Please take the time to study that sample, it will help you understand table views.

Comment: actually, init method are also called in another class. But, table are not reload.

Comment: actually, you need to understand what the init method is and when its called and why, your code above is horked

Answer (score 0):

UIView does not have a reloadData method. [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Maybe you can show your code so we can see what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob and i just used the viewDidLoad to add the data and in the end i used `[super loadView];` and it reload.